# Elasticsearch failed to parse query Cannot parse 'OR'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search for the word "OR" in document from index.

Here is the query I type

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "OR word1",
            "fields": [
              "field1"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse query [OR word1]",
        "index_uuid": "Brju2MNeQ5m7sI02Q2Y4gw",
        "index": "index_name"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "index_name",
        "node": "C5Suw-gaR7eehoH0WNGw1A",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "Failed to parse query [OR word1]",
          "index_uuid": "Brju2MNeQ5m7sI02Q2Y4gw",
          "index": "index_name",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot parse 'OR word1': Encountered \" <OR> \"OR \"\" at line 1, column 0.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    ",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "parse_exception",
              "reason": "Encountered \" <OR> \"OR \"\" at line 1, column 0.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    "
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Why is this an error and whats the correct way to overcome this? If I remove the word "Or" from the query it works fine however when i keep it it give me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your issue well, I created an index, and ingested two documents. I tried to devise a suggestion using the `escape` characters = `\\`

Here are the data I ingested:

"field1": "word1"

"field1": "OR word1"

Then, I did a small modification to your query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "word1 \\OR",
                    "fields": ["field1"]
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The response was:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "or-doc",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "9mCioHQBowpsxTkF3Jdx",
    "_score" : 0.0,
    "_source" : {
      "field1" : "word1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "or-doc",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "82CjoHQBowpsxTkFCZgE",
    "_score" : 0.0,
    "_source" : {
      "field1" : "OR word1"
    }
  }
]
```

Note: I escaped the `OR` as it is considered as a `reserved words`.

I will be glad to help if you have any issue.

Links: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use query_string, as mentioned in the [ES official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

> Because it returns an error for any invalid syntax, we don’t recommend
> using the query_string query for search boxes.
>
> If you don’t need to support a query syntax, consider using the match
> query. If you need the features of a query syntax, use the
> simple_query_string query, which is less strict.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "OR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof_63952836",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.43445712,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "OR word1"
                }
            }
        ]
```